# Rails web-console not showing up

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Althought I've been sure to add `<%= console %>` in my views (currently it resides in the application layout) the Rails web-console bundled with Rails isn't showing up.  I have `gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'` in my gemfile and was sure to bundle install.

I've gotten the console working in other applications, and it's super useful, but for some reason it simply won't show up here.  I even checked the page in Chrome's developer window, but it isn't there.

**application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Discite</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main-container" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="sidebar" class="col-xs-3">
      <!-- sidebar content -->
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="col-xs-9">
      <!--  main content -->
      <%= yield %>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<%= console %>

</body>
</html>
```

I even dropped this in the development config file
**development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
#...
  config.web_console.automount = true
#...
end
```

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: did u include gem and  `bundle` it ?

Comment: Of course. I tried to go up to 3.0 (which of course shouldn't be necessary) but couldn't because I'm on Ruby 2.1

Comment: Does this also happens at the '/' page? (we only got it working at the root, not on other pages).

Comment: I wanted to enable console in production and came upon the gotcha of having to [whitelist IP address](https://github.com/rails/web-console#configweb_consolewhitelisted_ips).